# React JSON schema double quotes encoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schema.org, json-ld

I am working on a React app which needs json-ld schema to be defined. I get the schema string through an API and need to add the appropriate script tag to my page.

My schema string looks something like this:

```
[{"@context": "http://schema.org"}]
```

I expect this to be translated to:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
   [{"@context": "http://schema.org"}]                    
</script>
```

However, I am having trouble dealing with the double quotes, as these get converted to html equivalent - `&quot;`

This is how my code looks like:

```
schemaString = "[{\"@context\": \"http://schema.org\"}]";

render() {
    return (<div>{schemaString &&
                <script type="application/ld+json">
                    {schemaString}
                </script>}
            </div>)
}
```

The html generated is:

```
<div>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
    [{&quot;@context&quot;: &quot;http://schema.org&quot;}]
  </script>
</div>
```

Any pointers on what I am missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `{JSON.stringify(schemaString)}`. It also may have to do with your script type.

Comment: Is it not possible to encode/decode using `encodeUriComponent` and `decodeUriComponent`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no reason to react-`render` script tags.

Answer (score 6):

Am I late? :) Make sure you place the script tag content by `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property. Also, don't forget to convert default object into proper JSON by `JSON.stringify()` method.

Like this:

```
return (
  <script
    type="application/ld+json"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(yourSchemaObject) }}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
schemaString = [{ "@context": "http://schema.org" }];
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {schemaString &&
                <script type="application/ld+json">
                    {JSON.stringify(schemaString)}
                </script>
            }
        </div>)
}
```